# Que significa HEAD -> USER1, origin/USER2, USER2

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-merge

Soy nuevo en Git estoy usándolo con un compañero. Cada uno trabaja en una rama suya. Cuando queramos unificar el codigo hacemos un merge:

```
julian@julian-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~/Escritorio/main$ git log --oneline --decorate
21ae88a (HEAD -> jonathan, origin/julian, julian) Rediseño de algunas paginas, cambio de estilos SASS instrucciones de uso..
6403044 Cambio de Readme
952bfe5 Cambio de Readme
cdc9f7e (origin, master) Primeros Cambios
```

¿Que significa "HEAD -> jonathan, origin/julian, julian"?

Comment: HEAD es un tipo de "componente" que apunta al último commit realizado (te invito a leer esta excelente [guía](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html) que me ayudo en mis inicios con Git :D); en cuanto al `origin/julian`, sólo está especificando que en tu repositorio remoto está apuntando a la rama julian que creaste para realizar los commits

Comment: No exactamente. `HEAD` es siempre donde estás parado... que no es lo mismo que el último commit que se hizo. Si haces `git checkout main~2`, `HEAD` se coloca en `main~2`, que estamos seguros que no es el último commit que se hizo.

Answer (score 0):

`HEAD` es siempre una referencia a donde estás parado. `HEAD -> jonathan` indica que estás trabajando sobre la rama local llamada `jonathan` y que estás en la revision`21ae88a`. `julian` es la rama local `julian` que está en esta misma revision.... y lo mismo la rama *remota* `origin/julian`.